# Accounting software that will allow me to sell prepaid blocks of time to clients

Tags: accounting, retainer

I am trying to locate an accounting package that will allow me to sell clients prepaid blocks of time (retainer) for my organizations services and then allow me to give them updated statements showing time remaining.

My preferences would be for non-cloud based.  I am currently using Quicken Home & Business but have not been able to find this capability in there.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you looked into a local installation of quickbooks? I think Quickbooks Pro 2014 has that functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use FrontAccounting (which is Web based, but on my own server, not in the cloud).

My handling of retainer-based client probably also works with some other packages.

Let's say a customer buys 100 hours at $90/hour.

There are two separate aspects to this: billing, and tracking the hours used. They may or may not be linked. I handle them completely separately.

Billing is easy: I invoice the customer for 100 hours @ $90 (or make it monthly installments, or whatever applies).

To track the hours, I then set up a sales order for 100 hours @ $0. As I perform the work, I enter deliveries against this sales order. This lets me track the number of hours actually used.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not aware of off the shelf software that will allow you to track prepaid blocks of time on retainer, a custom software solution built with FileMaker could certainly make this happen. For example, we use our product fmIgnite built on FileMaker to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://zapier.com/zapbook/google-calendar/paypal/.

Its free plan allows to automatically create Google calendar events when you receive a payment.